# Token Authorization with Java

Tags: java, servlets, api-key, http-status-code-401, apache-httpclient-5.x

I'm new coding servlets and I need to consume an API that my company given to me. The API application is another web app coded with Java.The API works in this way:

## 1. Authentication

You get your token by making a `POST` request to the API site, for example `https://the-api-site.com/api/login`, the params are `user` and `password`, and that gives to me a unique token.

## 2. Consuming the API

Here it is my problem, because now I have to use my token to consume the API with my Java application. The param that the API checks for the token is called `key`, so I try to call `https://the-api-site.com/api/resource?key=token`, and when I try it with the Advanced REST Client of Google, all works fine, but if I try it with my Java application I get 401 response.

I checked that the generated token is added to the URI of the GET Request.

Now I'll give you the code, all my comments are in the `GET` method, please tell me what am I doing wrong...

```
package connections;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import logs.Logger;
import org.apache.hc.client5.http.classic.methods.*;
import org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.*;
import org.apache.hc.core5.http.*;
import org.apache.hc.core5.http.io.entity.*;
import org.json.*;

public class APIRequest {
    private final String ENDPOINT = "http://the-api-site.com/api/";
    private JSONObject data;
    private Logger log;
    
    public APIRequest () {
        this.log = new Logger(); // This is a log utility coded by me, it is not part of the request.
    }
    
    public void write(String str) {
        try {
            this.log.write(str);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void write(JSONObject res) {
        try {
            String resStr = res.toString();
            this.log.write("result: \n\n"+resStr+"\n\n");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    
    public JSONObject execute(HttpPost request) throws ParseException, IOException {
        CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClients.createDefault();
        CloseableHttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        String status = response.toString();
        String code = String.valueOf(response.getCode());
        String result = "";
        if(entity != null) 
            result = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
        JSONObject res = new JSONObject();
        res.put("status", status);
        res.put("code", code);
        res.put("value", result);
        this.write(res);
        return res;
    }
    
    public JSONObject execute(HttpGet request) throws ParseException, IOException {
        CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClients.createDefault();
        CloseableHttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        String status = response.toString();
        String code = String.valueOf(response.getCode());
        String result = "";
        if(entity != null) 
            result = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
        JSONObject res = new JSONObject();
        res.put("status", status);
        res.put("code", code);
        res.put("value", result);
        
        String resStr = res.toString();
        this.write(res);
        return res;
    }
    
    public JSONObject post(String url, JSONObject data) throws IOException, InterruptedException, ParseException {
        String uri = this.ENDPOINT+url;
        HttpPost request = new HttpPost(uri);
        request.setEntity(new StringEntity(data.toString()));
        request.addHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json");
        this.log.write("POST REQUEST: "+request.getRequestUri());
        return this.execute(request);
    }
    
    public JSONObject post(String token, String url, JSONObject data) throws IOException, InterruptedException, ParseException {
        String uri = this.ENDPOINT+url;
        HttpPost request = new HttpPost(uri);
        request.setEntity(new StringEntity(data.toString()));
        request.addHeader("key", token);
        request.addHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json");
        this.write("POST REQUEST: "+request.getRequestUri());
        return this.execute(request);
    }
    
    public JSONObject get(String tok /** here I give the token */, String url /** in this case would be "resource" */) throws IOException, InterruptedException, ParseException, URISyntaxException {
        String token = "3ru3t4tc1qcq36epl0ss222evn"; // Here I tried the Advanced REST Client working token. Works in Advanced REST Client, but not here.
        String apiUrl = this.ENDPOINT+url+"?key="+token; // Here I tried to set the token same way to the Advanced REST Client.
        HttpGet request = new HttpGet(apiUrl);
        /*URI uri = new URIBuilder(request.getUri())
                .addParameter("key", token)
                .build();
        request.setUri(uri);*/ // This is another way I tried to set the token...
        request.addHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json");
        // request.addHeader("key", token);  // ... And another way
        this.write("GET REQUEST: "+request.getRequestUri());
        this.write("GET SCHEME: "+request.getScheme());
        return this.execute(request);
        // Nothing worked yet, all the times I did this request I got 401.
        // The token I generate on Advanced REST Client doesn't works here, and the Token I generate here doesn't workd in Advanced REST Client either.
    }
}
```

Thanks for the help!

### EDIT

Here is the log that I generate when I run `this.log.write(args)`:

```
[2022-05-17 11:44:41.967] POST REQUEST: /api/login
[2022-05-17 11:44:41.967] POST SCHEME: http
[2022-05-17 11:44:42.168] result: 
{"code":"200","value":"jkuojnm06jr4a2cp7rbq14ifst","status":"200  HTTP/1.1"}

[2022-05-17 11:44:42.168] GET REQUEST: /api/products?key=3ru3t4tc1qcq36epl0ss222evn
[2022-05-17 11:44:42.168] GET SCHEME: http
[2022-05-17 11:44:42.189] result: 
{"code":"401","value":"{\"timestamp\":1652780682176,\"status\":401,\"error\":\"Unauthorized\",\"message\":\"The user is not logged.\",\"path\":\"/api/products\"}","status":"401  HTTP/1.1"}
```

### EDIT 2

In this case I'm using the token generated by the application (the first one I was using a token that I knew that was working because it was working on Advanced REST Client).

```
[2022-05-17 15:54:15.618] POST REQUEST: /api/login
[2022-05-17 15:54:15.618] POST SCHEME: http
[2022-05-17 15:54:15.948] result: 

{"code":"200","value":"kr72qkk563b6h58nd2017ml225","status":"200  HTTP/1.1"}



[2022-05-17 15:54:15.95] GET REQUEST: /api/products?key=kr72qkk563b6h58nd2017ml225
[2022-05-17 15:54:15.95] GET SCHEME: http
[2022-05-17 15:54:15.96] result: 

{"code":"401","value":"{\"timestamp\":1652795655953,\"status\":401,\"error\":\"Unauthorized\",\"message\":\"The user is not logged.\",\"path\":\"/api/products\"}","status":"401  HTTP/1.1"}
```

Comment: In that particular request the token you use `3ru...` doesn't match the token you just received back `jku...`, so it makes sense that this request wouldn't work.  Do you have an example where the token you receive is used in the example request?

Comment: I know is not the same token, I tried to use the API generated token that I generated with the app and the token that I generated in Google Advanced REST Client, but i doesn't works with any of them. Anyways I'll add a log of one test using the token from the app

Comment: Sorry.  This may be another bad question.  Your endpoint is defined as `https` but your logging shows `http`.  Could it be that the advanced rest client is defaulting to `https` and there is a requirement of the api to allow access only over `https` (which is reasonable in most case).

Comment: Sorry, my fault changing the endpoint in the example, I'm using an API hosted in http domain

Comment: Hrm.. if that's the case then the only thing I can say is look into the API/Auth more.  It's either something to do with the timing of the request (if key needs to match session) or if there are other missing headers/cookies that the rest client adds automatically.

Comment: I checked the headers from the Google ARC and I set the same headers and cookies, I can't understand why it's not working...

Comment: Without understanding how the API does it's authentication, it's hard to say.  With just `key=` it should work.  Which means there must be something else in the API Auth that is stopping it from working.

Comment: Solved! The API was giving me a `token` for the `HttpClient` that did the login request, my code was creating a new HttpClient object everytime I made a query, so that was the reason I was getting the 401 error, because the new client was not logged. Thanks for the help anyways :)